# Finding attribute of record being the MAX of something in GROUP BY statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

This is a bit of a hard question to formulate (any edits are appreciated) but here goes. Let's say you have two tables: `FRUIT` and `BASKET`. Fruits (representing actual items, not fruit species) are grouped by baskets. Here is one example of `FRUIT`:

```
FRUIT_ID  WEIGHT_IN_GRAMS  BASKET_ID FRUIT_TYPE
--------  ---------------  --------- ----------
1         100              1         Apple     
2         200              1         Orange    
3         150              1         Lemon     
4         100              2         Apple
5         300              2         Plum
```

What I want is `FRUIT_ID` of the **heaviest fruit in each basket**. In other words:

```
FRUIT_ID  BASKET_ID  FRUIT_TYPE
--------  ---------  ----------
2         1          Orange
5         2          Plum
```

Here is the SQL I have come up with to find this:

```
select fruit_id, basket_id, fruit_type
  from fruit f
  join (select basket_id, max(weight_in_grams) max_weight
          from fruit
         group by basket_id) t on f.basket_id = t.basket_id
                              and f.weight_in_grams = t.max_weight;
```

This could work except that **`WEIGHT_IN_GRAMS` is not guaranteed to be unique**. In the case where there were duplicates, I'd want the one which is alphabetically last.

Any takers?

**PS**: I know I could wrap my query above in yet another query, but this feels rather messy, so what I'm looking for is optimizing this if at all possible.

Comment: I don't really see how your BASKET table fits into all this. You seem to be joining FRUIT to FRUIT. Can you post the exact definitions of each table?

Comment: The BASKET table is really just an arbitrary grouping of fruits. This is an analogy for the actual problem I have, the details of which would make this problem even more incomprehensible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use dense_rank to assign numbers to each row. `partition by` creates groups that have their own sequences (in this case each basket). `order by` specifies the sorting, so order by weight first (descending), and name second.

The first row of each basket gets the number 1. Then, wrap the query to be able to select only the rows that got number 1. You'll need to do this in a subquery, because analytic functions cannot be used in the where clause, and neither in the having clause, I believe.

```
select
    fruit_id, basket_id, fruit_type, weight_in_grams
from
    (select
      fruit_id, basket_id, fruit_type, weight_in_grams,
      dense_rank() over (partition by basket_id order by weight_in_grams desc, fruit_type desc) as rank
    from
      fruit f)
where
    rank = 1
```

Comment: Don't you want to sort on fruit_type DESC in the OVER clause, so that you get the alphabetically last one in case of ties on weight, os OP desires?

Comment: @DCookie. Thanks. I must have overlooked that 'last' in the question. :) Fixed it.

Comment: Oracle never ceases to amaze with its proprietary magic. Thanks!